# Windows 7 Permissions Issue

Tags: windows-7, permissions

i think i made a mistake !

on my root folder under apache web server, i give the permisseion to the computer name only. so now no one including me or the admin can open the folder! and i got (forbedden access) when trying to access localhost or my webpage under apache

is there any way to restore previous permissions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an administrator, take ownership of the folder first, then you can reset the permissions.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx

Comment: Thanks it works! i could now open the folder but still can't access all the sub folders, also can't access localhost or my webpage. do i need to take ownership of all sub folders and files?